# Using XPath with more than one XML file

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I am trying to write an XPath query to find the locations of authors of papers which were published in 2008. I have two files, `authors.xml` and `papers.xml`. I have added a fragment of each file below to illustrate the structures of each.

How do I write an XPath query that gets information from both files? I have written a query to get the locations of each author, but I do not know how to extend this to limit the results to authors who published in 2008.

My current XPath query:

```
doc("authors.xml")//author/location
```

Current output (locations of all authors):

```
<location>Berkeley</location>
<location>Stanford</location>
```

Desired output (locations of only authors who published in 2008):

```
<location>Berkeley</location>
```

`authors.xml`:

```
<authorRoot>
    <author>
        <first>John</first>
        <last>Doe</last>
        <location>Berkeley</location>
    </author>
    <author>
        <first>Don</first>
        <last>Knuth</last>
        <location>Stanford</location>
    </author>
</authorRoot>
```

`papers.xml`:

```
<paperRoot>
    <paper>
        <journal>
            <author>Don Knuth</author>
            <title>TeX for fun</title>
            <year>1995</year>
        </journal>
    </paper>
    <paper>
        <book>
            <author>Jack Daniels</author>
            <title>The Ballmer Peak</title>
            <year>2004</year>
        </book>
    </paper>
    <paper>
        <journal>
            <author>John Doe</author>
            <title>P equals NP</title>
            <year>2008</year>
        </journal>
    </paper>
</paperRoot>
```

Comment: What environment / platform are you attempting this in?  XSLT, perhaps?

Comment: The `document` function is only available in XSLT, not pure XPath. XPath 2.0 has the very similar `doc` function but there's no equivalent in pure XPath 1.0.

Comment: I've revised the `document`/`doc` function issue. I did not know there was a distinction, as both forms worked in my query. I am using Galax to run my XPath queries.

Comment: This is a question about XQuery then. I have edited your question. Please show what exactly the output should be.

Comment: I have added the current output and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now that we've established XPath 2.0, we can use a for statement.

```
for $a in doc('authors.xml')/*/author 
    return
    if (doc('papers.xml')
    /*/paper/*[author = concat($a/first, ' ', $a/last)]
    /year[. = '2008'])
    then $a/location else ()
```

This could all be on one line, but please don't do so.  If whitespace is allowed, use it for readability.